# Installation of Jetty into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jsf, jetty

I've had Jetty recommended as a good container for fast and simple development, in my case, Java Server Faces. I wish to use it with my Eclipse IDE (Version: 3.4.1), but quite frankly, can't figure out how.

I've tried various outdated plugins, only with large amounts of errors in return, so I'm hoping someone could guide me from downloading the right version to installing it, and being able to press "RUN", and see a simple Hello World in JSP/JSF work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could follow that tutorial from the [eclipse help pages](https://github.com/eclipse/webtools.jsf.docs/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user/html/tasks/add_jsf_facet.html).

But check the version of your [jetty](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/). From [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg17014.html), V6 is recommended (V9 would work too, from [Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84118/jacob)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022095/installation-of-jetty-into-eclipse/1022194#comment19231834_1022194)).

[image: addprojectfacet.png]

> I believe the J2EE Preview server is hard coded to that internal Eclipse supplied version of Jetty.
>   However, you can execute "`Window -> Preferences`" and on the "`Server -> Server Runtime Environments`" page, click the `Add` button. Click the "`Download additional server adapters`" link and a dialog should appear and eventually list a Jetty Generic Server Adapter you can try.

Comment: @Jacob interesting. I have included your comment in the answer and restored the picture.

Comment: Hey hi @VonC I did what you said for my prject but it is giving me some `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. Can you please help out why is it so?

Comment: @TejasSaitwal 6 years later, it would be best to make a new question, with your current version of Eclipse, java, OS and other details.

Comment: I am using windows 7, jetty 8 and eclipse is luna 4.4.1

Comment: @TejasSaitwal I meant, as a separate question, visible by all, not buried in a comment ;)

Comment: @VonC [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33430675/connection-pooling-using-jetty-in-oracle). I have asked the question already, please look into it if you can. Thanks.

Comment: @VonC Any update? I am able to do the connection pooling successfully with tomcat on the same servlet.

Answer (score 9):

I use the [Run Jetty Run](http://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/) plugin.  Its very simple and easy to use

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the below steps to set up Jetty server in my eclipse:

(1) Download the 'net.sourceforge.eclipsejetty.launcher' jar (plugin) from the below URL:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-jetty/

(2) Copy the downloaded jar file to your eclipse 'plugins' folder (Example: C:\eclipse-jee-luna\plugins)

(3) Restart Eclipse

(4) Go to Eclipse Workspace -> Right click on your web project -> Run -> Run Configurations -> Jetty Web App -> Set the 'WebApp Directory' -> Click on Run

[image]

After following the above steps, I am able to successfully deploy & run my web project using Jetty Server in Eclipse.

I hope this is helpful.